# Doctrine 1.2: Adding validation method to record template

Tags: validation, model, doctrine, behavior, doctrine-1.2

In a Doctrine Record object, I can add the following method to validate data:

```
protected function validate()
{
    if (empty($this->first_name) && empty($this->last_name) && empty($this->company)) {
        $this->getErrorStack()->add('company', 'You must fill in at least one of the following: First Name, Last Name, Company');
    }
}
```

How do I add similar code to an attached Template object?

Comment: Don't get it. Can you please provide more information about what you want to do?

Comment: @Timo, Doctrine has behaviors. Using behaviors, I can assign functionality for multiple models. How do I include validation in a behavior? Please let me know if you still don't understand. Also, please be more specific about the part you do not understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried also, but it looks like it can't be done in behaviour class. To avoid that, in preValidate method I placed code that would check that additional columns.

I would recommend you to not change validate() method, but to use preValidate($event) and postValidate($event) public methods. It should look like:

```
public function preValidate(Doctrine_Event $event)
{
   ... your custom validation logic...
   parent::preValidate($event) ;
}
```

Comment: I'll definitely check this out, thanks! Thought this question would go unanswered.